# How to bind the ViewModel to the View with SimpleIoc

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using MVVMLight framework and I try to use dependency injection when I instanciate a View. When the View is extracted from the service locator SimpleIoc, I want that SimpleIoc creates a new instance of this View and pass as parameter its ViewModel. How should I register the View with its ViewModel in the SimpleIoC to get this approach? At the moment I do the register like that:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
```

But I am try to do that:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMainView, MainViewModel>();
```

assuming that the MainViewModel is a new instance of the view model for MainView (that implements the interface IMainView).

How do I have to register View and ViewModel in my SimpleIoC and how do I have to call the View applying dependency injection with its references (with its ViewModel)?

Update:

My current code:

ViewModelLocator.cs

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{

    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<NewsViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TeamsViewModel>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Main property.
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
        "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
        Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public NewsViewModel NewsViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<NewsViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public TeamsViewModel TeamsViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TeamsViewModel>();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cleans up all the resources.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Height="30" Width="40" Command="{Binding OpenNews}">News</Button>
        <Button Height="30" Width="40" Margin="5,0,0,0" Command="{Binding OpenTeams}">Teams</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter  Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the current view model.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentViewModel == value)
                return;
            _currentViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(CurrentViewModelPropertyName);
        }
    }

    #region Commands

    public RelayCommand OpenNews { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand OpenTeams { get; set; }

    #endregion

    private void RegisterCommands()
    {
        OpenNews = new RelayCommand(ShowOpenNews);
        OpenTeams = new RelayCommand(ShowOpenTeams);

    }

    private void ShowOpenTeams()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TeamsViewModel>(); //MainViewModel.TeamsViewModel;
    }

    private void ShowOpenNews()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<NewsViewModel>();
    }
```

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NewsViewModel}">
        <view:NewsView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TeamsViewModel}">
        <view:TeamView/>
    </DataTemplate>        
    <!--Global View Model Locator-->
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                         d:IsDataSource="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

At the moment I change the current view through DataTemplates and change the property CurrentViewModel. (Now ViewModel firstandI want View first)

I want to do Dependency Injection and use the SimpleIOC but I don't know how to put into play that.

Comment: if you register your viewModel as IViewmodel, why don't you put a IViewModel parameter on constructor of your View, so that your IOC Container can resolve your dependency for you?

Comment: I am getting an Exception. I am doing the following:
I register the ViewModels in my ViewModelLocator like that:            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INewsViewModel>();
And my ViewModel is so defined: public class NewsViewModel : ViewModelBase, INewsViewModel.

My View constructor has a parameter, the viewmodel: 
        public NewsView(INewsViewModel dc)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = dc;
        }

Comment: please edit your question with all necessary code(the mapping of your entities)

Comment: @InvernoMuto I have updated my question. At the moment I don't use dependency injection and I want toset the DataContext to the view not throug Datatemplate but by passing to the view as parameter. I don't know how I should start with.